# Attaching a listener to `MIDIGetNumberOfSources`

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, coremidi

Im working on a CoreMIDI project, where I want to run a function, every time either a device is added or removed. What I know you can check is `MIDIGetNumberOfSources` for the number of MIDI sources connected, but is it possible to attach perhaps a listener or an observer to the function, so I can run a fucntion every time a change occurs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You do that in your MIDINotifyBlock.

Look at the notification passed in.

```
func MyMIDINotifyBlock(midiNotification: UnsafePointer<MIDINotification>) {        
    let notification = midiNotification.pointee

    switch notification.messageID {
       // Some aspect of the current MIDISetup has changed.
    case.msgSetupChanged:
```